# Bitwise Operators: Using only & and ~ to get ^

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, boolean-algebra

I've been stuck on a bonus my professor gave for a couple of days now:

- *give x^y using only ~ and &*
- *Assume the machine use twos complement, 32-bit representations of integers.*

I've tried many different combinations, and also tried to write out the logic of the operator ^, but it hasn't been working out. Any hints or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [de-morgans law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) might help

Comment: [Is XOR a combination of AND and NOT operators?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38473/is-xor-a-combination-of-and-and-not-operators)

Comment: @EdHeal I saw this earlier on another question, but I couldn't find the XOR proof, I'll look at it again, thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate#/media/File:XOR_from_NAND.svg

Comment: I failed to grasp the relevance of 2-compl in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XOR operator can in fact be written as a combination of those two. I'll put this in two steps:

> A NAND B = NOT(A AND B)
>
> A XOR B = (A NAND (A NAND B)) NAND (B NAND (A NAND B))

As described before on math:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38473/is-xor-a-combination-of-and-and-not-operators

Comment: That's a lot of operations!

Comment: I'll gladly golf that down in a couple of days, when he's past his submission date.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The reason for implementing this in terms of NAND alone is that its cheaper (in hardware) to have lots of one kind of gate than smaller numbers of different kinds of gates. You don't rewrite XOR in terms of NAND because you are trying to optimize a software implementation.

Comment: @chepner sure, but wikipedia has a four NAND gate version.  I do agree that a five gate version implements the "definition" of xor more idiomatically, but it is still a lot more gates...

Answer (score 2):

First, suppose you had each of the `&`, `|`, and `~` operators available to you. Could you implement `^` that way?

Next, see if you can find a way to express `|` purely in terms of `&` and `~`.

Finally, combine those ideas together.

Good luck!

Comment: Somebody already posted the answer, but I like your style because it makes me understand through proofing it myself. I'm going to try this and then see if I can get to the answer by myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: OP requested "Any hints or help would be much appreciated!" and this post answers that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to draw the truth tables for **XOR**, **AND**, and, **OR**

```
a b  a^b
0 0   0
0 1   1
1 0   1
1 1   0

a b  a|b
0 0   0
0 1   1
1 0   1
1 1   1

a b  a&b
0 0   0
0 1   0
1 0   0
1 1   1
```

next find how to use `|` and `&` to build this

`a|b` give all the three first rows correct, `a&b` give the other line. If we negate it it can be used to mask the wanted lines! So we could phrase xor as:

(a **or** b) *but* **not** when (a **and** b)

There is no *but* in boolean algebra so it becomes an **and** which leads to this:

```
(a|b)&~(a&b)
```

*Edit:*
Pointed out I was answering the wrong question, use The law of DeMorgan to build the or

```
~(~a & ~b)
```

gives the answer to be

```
~(~a&~b)&~(a&b)
```

Comment: Reading the question ;-)